# Can you have alias in Julia?

Tags: arrays, variables, julia, alias

Suppose that I have plenty of different variables:

`t_time, m_time, s_time, TL_reached, gap, UB, LB, nopt_cons, nsubtour_cons, nconnectivity_cuts, nhubs, m_cost, sp_cost`

Can I allias them and instead of writing:

`t_time, m_time, s_time, TL_reached, gap, UB, LB, nopt_cons, nsubtour_cons, nconnectivity_cuts, nhubs, m_cost, sp_cost = [t_time, m_time, s_time, TL_reached, gap, UB, LB, nopt_cons, nsubtour_cons, nconnectivity_cuts, nhubs, m_cost, sp_cost]./5`

write something that would be similar to:

`alias vars = 't_time, m_time, s_time, TL_reached, gap, UB, LB, nopt_cons, nsubtour_cons, nconnectivity_cuts, nhubs, m_cost, sp_cost'`

And finally:

`vars = [vars]./5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a language feature for anything like this. You could probably do it with a macro but it seems a bit ill advised. It might make more sense to capture all thees fields in data structure; if they're all the same type (e.g. `Float64`) then you could use `AxisArrays` to associate names to the dimensions of a vector of values. If they're of heterogenous types, then you could make a custom struct type and define the arithmetic operations that you want to perform on the type.

Comment: What if I use `@with_kw` from `Parameters.jl`, cf. `https://stackoverflow.com/q/71767146/10094437`?

Comment: @JKHA This is exactly what was suggested by Stefan: "It might make more sense to capture all thees fields in data structure"