# Unexported function aliases in module

Tags: package, namespaces, julia, metaprogramming

Decades of research & software lead to many synonyms for functions that users could expect to "just work" in my module. There are roughly 80 aliases I want to support, yet not export. For example, imagine `:bar`, `:qux`, `"bar"`, `"qux"` to be aliases for `Base.sqrt` as an input to struct `Bar`.

**Question**: What is the recommended way to create unexported aliases for functions in a module?

I have read the [module documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage-1) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71768925/14853907) question and searched codebases on GitHub. Below are my attemps, `Bar2` is faster, but goes against "avoid globals in the namespace".

```
# approach 1: add to namespace, but don't export
module Foo1
    struct Bar1 fun::Function end
    Bar1(fun::Union{Symbol, String}) = Bar1(getfield(@__MODULE__, Symbol(fun)))

    const baz = const qux = √ # ...

    export Bar1
end

# approach 2: package internal dictionary, not in namespace
module Foo2
    struct Bar2 fun::Function end
    Bar2(fun::Union{Symbol, String}) = Bar2(alias[Symbol(fun)])

    const alias = Base.ImmutableDict(:baz => √, :qux => √) #...

    export Bar2
end

using .Foo1, .Foo2

Bar1(:baz).fun == Bar1("qux").fun == Bar2(:baz).fun == Bar2("qux").fun # true
```